# Web scraping using python, how to deal with ngif?

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, scrapy

I'm trying to read the price of a fund which is not available through an API. The fund is listed here https://bors.e24.no/#!/instrument/KL-AFMI2.OSE

At first I thought this would be a simple task so I looked at beautifulsoup, but realized that what I wanted was not returned. A far as I can tell due to the:

```
 <-- ngIf: $root.allowStreamingToggle -->
```

I'm a beginner so hoping someone can help me with an easy way to get this value.

Comment: I don't see `ngif` in HTML. There is `ng-if="$root.allowStreamingToggle"` which means some JavaScript Framework which adds data to page. You will have to use `Selenium` to get data. OR you may try to find url used by JavaScript to get data and then use `requests` to get it.

Comment: Is the expected result c.1 961,74 ?

Comment: Yep, thats the result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I see json being returned from the following endpoint in network tab

```
import requests

headers = {'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'}
r = requests.get('https://bors.e24.no/server/components/graphdata/(PRICE)/DAY/KL-AFMI2.OSE?points=500&stop=2019-07-30&period=1weeks', headers = headers).json()
```

Price is then

```
r['rows'][0]['values']['series']['c1']['data'][3][1]
```

Comment: Any idea what the date (stop=2019-07-30) in the URL is for?  I tried changing it far back in time and it didn't change the response, however changing to a future date gave an error.

Comment: I assume it is for end date

Answer (score 2):

The tag "ngIf" almost certainly means that the website you are attempting to scrape is an AngularJS app... in which case, the data is almost certainly NOT in the HTML page you are pulling and attempting to parse with BeautifulSoup.

Rather, the page is probably pulling the data later -- say, via AJAX -- and the rendering it IN to the page via Angular's client-side code.

If all that is right... then BeautifulSoup is not the right tool.

You might have some hope if you can identify the AJAX call that the page is calling, then call THAT directly.  Inspect it to see the data structure; if you are lucky maybe it is JSON and then super easy to parse.  If that looks promising, then you can probably simply use the `requests` library, and skip BeautifulSoup.  But you have to do the reverse engineering to figure out WHAT you should be calling.

Here, try this: I did a little snooping with the browser console.  Is this the data you are looking for?  [get info for **KL-AFMI2.OSE**](https://bors.e24.no/server/components/graphdata/(PRICE)/DAY/KL-AFMI2.OSE?points=500&stop=2019-07-30&period=1weeks)

If so.. then just use that URL directly in `requests`.